# 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' when consuming arc gis map service from WP8

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8, arcgis, arcgis-server

I have published an arc gis map on arc gis (local) server  as a service
I want to consume it in windows phone 8 app 
using Arc Gis Phone SDK for .Net 
when I run the emulator I get:

```
[An exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' ]occurred in System.ni.dll but was not handled in user code]
```

the inner exception details :

```
the remote server reply with  not found
```

I can't find any solution and this exception appears with all code samples.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows Phone you'll need to make sure you're not using "localhost" or similar in the url for ArcGIS, you'll need the server name or IP address (just in case!).

You'll may also need to add a firewall rule to allow access to the ArcGIS endpoint on your machine even if you have both the ArcGIS server and Windows Phone Emulator on the same box. It's not 100% clear from your question, but I guess from your "(local)" that they might be.

I've had the emulator talking to IIS on the same machine, but it did require a firewall rule adding to my local machine as I have a firewall installed locally.

I hope that helps.